# What "Whisky Goggles" means?

Tags: metaphors

Quote:

> The Whisky Goggles Effect
>
> There seems to be some evidence that Agile and Scrum can nudge the
>   marginally incompetent into being marginally employable. I call this
>   the Whisky Goggles Effect: it turns the 3s and 4s into 5s, but it
>   makes you so sloppy that the 7s and 9s want nothing to do with you.
>   Unable to get their creative juices flowing under aggressive
>   micromanagement, the best programmers leave.

From: https://michaelochurch.wordpress.com/2015/06/06/why-agile-and-especially-scrum-are-terrible/

Looks like some sort of distorted perception that is happening when you drunk or something but I can't fully understand what does it mean exactly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whiskey goggles (or beer goggles) refers to a change in perception caused by alcohol. Specifically, that drunk men tend to see women as far more attractive than they would when sober: Hence various jokes about men going to bed with a supermodel and waking up next to Godzilla.

The numbers here probably refer to some people's rather crass habit of rating women on a scale of 1 to 10.

Comment: you know, I didn't realise what the writer was getting at with the numbers {like the old movie "ten"} .. great point.

Comment: And here's the bizarre Tony Millionaire with a usage example of such terms http://www.achewood.com/index.php?date=11022009

Comment: @JoeBlow I hadn't seen your edited answer. I was replying to your comment. If you had said you had edited the post, I would have reversed my downvote. P.S In my opinion, there are better examples on the web that explain/support the meaning of beer goggles.

Comment: No matter - as long as everyone reading now knows what the text in question is about!  vote -- do you mean that number thing on the side with the arrows?  ok  :)

Comment: Oh now I got it thanks! The article was about developers but I couldn't get it till you pointed me to women.